# How to deploy web app without sharing env file

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, github, pipeline

I am deploying a node.js app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk using the following tutorial :
https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/node-elastic-beanstalk/

I do wish to use the pipeline integration with github but I see a small problem.

My node.js app use MongoDb atlas and as such have some credentials store in an .env file.
This .env file is excluded from the files on the github repository for security reason.
Thing is, connection is impossible without this file.

How can I deploy my node.js app using a pipeline on a public github repository without showing the .env file to the entire world ?

Thank you

Comment: You can pass them to your EB app [directly through config in the AWS console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-softwaresettings.html#environments-cfg-softwaresettings-console). If you want to do it in the pipeline, you can use [eb setenv](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-pass-variables/) with [GitHub's secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets#accessing-your-secrets).